# Twitter OAuth fails to validate my Python command line tool

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I have spent hours in frustration and now I have this:

```
import requests, json, urllib
import time
import string, random

from hashlib import sha1
import hmac, binascii

def twitterIDGenerator(length):
    toRet = ""
    for i in range(0, length):
        toRet = toRet + random.choice(string.hexdigits)
    return toRet

def twitterSignatureGenerator(baseString, keyString):
    hashed = hmac.new(keyString, baseString, sha1)
    return binascii.b2a_base64(hashed.digest()).rstrip('\n')

OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = ''
OAUTH_NONCE = twitterIDGenerator(32)
OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD = 'HMAC-SHA1'
OAUTH_TIMESTAMP = str(int(time.time()))
OAUTH_VERSION = '1.0'

# Get request token from Twitter
request_tokenURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'

request_tokenParameterString = ("oauth_consumer_key=" + OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY + 
        "&oauth_nonce=" + OAUTH_NONCE + "&oauth_signature_method=" + 
        OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD + "&oauth_timestamp=" + OAUTH_TIMESTAMP + 
        "&oauth_version=" + OAUTH_VERSION)
request_tokenSigBaseString = ("POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&" +
        urllib.quote(request_tokenParameterString))

request_tokenSignature = twitterSignatureGenerator(request_tokenSigBaseString, 
        '[REDACTED consumer secret key]')
request_tokenHeaders = {'oauth_nonce': OAUTH_NONCE,
                        'oauth_callback': 'oob',
                        'oauth_signature_method': OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD,
                        'oauth_timestamp': OAUTH_TIMESTAMP,
                        'oauth_consumer_key': OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,
                        'oauth_signature': urllib.quote(request_tokenSignature),
                        'oauth_version': OAUTH_VERSION}

request_tokenResponse = requests.post(request_tokenURL, headers=request_tokenHeaders)
print request_tokenResponse.text
```

So far, it is supposed to return a request_token so I can have my user go to the PIN website so I can get the access_token. But I just get "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" from Twitter.

A possible reason for this is wrong URL encoding. I see that Twitter needs RFC3986 encoding. Is there a way to do this in Python? If yes, should I do it only at the two locations I am currently using urllib.quote? Is my oauth_signature generated correctly?

[The documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature#note-sorting) is annoyingly convoluted.

Comment: From what I remember when I implemented it in perl, the documentation is actually quite explicit. Did you check that with the same inputs they use, you get the same signature and request? Note an important point: `urllib.quote` may not escape just those characters they want you to: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/percent-encoding-parameters

Comment: Also there are Python libs for OAuth: http://oauth.net/code/